# touchBegin is only called when it has color

Tags: ios

I have a view(MatrixView), nothing fancy, just inherited from UIView. The view's touchBegin is only called if I set the color?

```
MatrixView view = [[MatrixView alloc] initWithFrame:[self view]bounds];
// view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

I sounds strange?

Comment: So if you do not set the color, is the view still visible?

Comment: yes, I have tried to add subView in the MatrixView's viewDidLoad - and they show up. I have done this is in a simple test project - as I saw the problem in a bigger project.